C# Find specific text in multiline textbo
I am trying to create an app with a find in text function (see attached graphic):

I can't find any way to have it search in a multiline textbox and highlight (select) the word in the textbox. I will be adding a "Find Next" function as well. Everything I have found is either using SQL commands or just returning the line number of the text, or just searching in a file. I am not using SQL, and the text in the textbox might not be saved to a file yet.
EDIT: I found how to do what I want. I have edited the code below to the working code in case anyone needs it in the future.
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtSearchText.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You must type a search term in the text box, or press the close button.", "Error!",
 MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
else
{
 strSearchString = txtSearchText.Text;
 int index = txtMain.Text.IndexOf(strSearchString);
 txtMain.Select(index,strSearchString.Length);
 txtMain.Focus();
 txtMain.ScrollToCaret();
    
}


Look at the IndexOf method of the String class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-8.0

Seems like 3 questions in one: get string from an input box & search through string & highlight the text in the input box .  Which ones can't you do?

I need to be able to read the text in the main textbox and locate the word that I have typed into the textbox on the find dialog and then highlight it. I know how to read the text of the textbox on the find dialog into a variable, and I know how to find a substring of a string, but I don't know how to highlight that substring in the textbox.

I added some additional code to the event handler, however I found it does not work.

I found the code does work, but only when I change focus to the main form. Also, if the text is off screen, it won't go to that location before highlighting it.

Perhaps you could post the code that "does not work" and the code that does so that we can see what you're seeing.

@Tornado726 - Is this WinForms? If so, you should add a winforms tag to the question.  Your approach should work based on the documentation, see in debug mode if your index and length get the expected values. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-select-text-in-the-windows-forms-textbox-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

I found how to do what I wanted. The code below is the working code:
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtSearchText.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You must type a search term in the text box, or press the close button.", "Error!",
 MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
else
{
 strSearchString = txtSearchText.Text;
 int index = txtMain.Text.IndexOf(strSearchString);
 txtMain.Select(index,strSearchString.Length);
 txtMain.Focus();
 txtMain.ScrollToCaret();
    
}


Will that work when the string is not found? Hint: No it will crash
